# Ratio isn't answering correct for this problem

Tags: problem-solving

Assume there are 2 products A and B made by different companies. Product A costs 1.2006 USD and Product B costs 2.8298 USD. They decided to exchange their products equally without using Money as a channel. Now I need to find how many products B the other company get in exchange of product A or vice versa.

I used Ratios to calculate this but couldn't get correct answer.

```
Quantities

A = 10,000
B = ?

A : 1.2006 :: B : 2.8298
```

After calculating this, I'm getting products B more than products A are exchanged which is not possible in practice. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you show what you have done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total value of A is $A \cdot 1.2006$, while the value of B is $B \cdot 2.8298$, so set these equal.  Clearly $B \lt A$